# Find the maximum and minimum values in a column? The values are percentages

Tags: excel, vba, max, min

I need to script a function to pull the minimum and maximum values from one column. The values are percentages so I'm not sure if that will trip up the function since it's not an integer?

I tried

```
gp_increase = Worksheet.Function.max(Range("K"))
```

and

```
gp_decrease = Worksheet.Function.max(Range("K"))
```

I got a

> "Run-time error '424': Object Required.

Comment: Try `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("K:K"))`

Comment: `Range("K")` is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead for the max value:

```
gp_increase = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("K:K"))
```

And this for the minimum value:

```
gp_decrease =Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("K:K"))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!